# Typescript to Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

We are converting the existing Javascript to Typescript.

When the Typescript code is compiled to Javascript, there is __extends method call. But there is NO function definition for __extends. So, getting the error as __extends as undefined.  I believe __extends will be created in the Javascript file.

Is there any configuration change, that we should do inorder to get the __extends function in the compiled Javascript ?

Please advice and throw some help.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": { 
    "target": "es5", 
    "outDir": "../app/scripts/",
    "rootDir": "./", 
    "watch": false, 
    "removeComments": true, 
    "module": "amd", 
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "outDir": "../app/scripts/",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "watch": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noEmitHelpers": true     
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this TS issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2009) either remove the `noEmitHelpers` option from tsconfig.json file or provide __extends method yourself.